# JQuery Will Not Run In ASPX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, cloudinary

I am trying to use the Cloudinary JQuery SDK in a .aspx page, using the following code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.cloudinary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Ready!");
        $.cloudinary.config({
            cloud_name: 'MYCLOUD'
        })

        $('.cloudinary_fileupload').unsigned_cloudinary_upload('MYUNSIGNEDUPLOADPRESET', {
            cloud_name: 'MYCLOUD',
            tags: 'browser_uploads'
        }, {
            multiple: true
        })
        .bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) {
            // inspect data.result for return value with link to the uploaded image and more
            console.log('Upload result', data.result);
            // Create a thumbnail of the uploaded image, with 150px width
            var image = $.cloudinary.image(
                data.result.public_id, {
                    secure: true,
                    width: 150,
                    crop: 'scale'
                });
            $('.gallery').prepend(image);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="JQuery">
        <input name="file" type="file" class="cloudinary-fileupload"/>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Unfortunately, when I select an image, nothing occurs and the upload is never completed.

Can anyone point out what is wrong might be stopping the JQuery script from working as expected?

Comment: There's some basic debugging you need to do. Do all the scripts load when you look in your browser's network tab? Do you get any errors in your JavaScript console? Does anything get logged in the console? These are the sort of details you need to put in your question.

Comment: Thanks @mason. All the scripts get loaded, but there are two versions of JQuery. There are no errors in the JavaScript console. The “Ready” message from my code is the only thing that gets logged to the console. Nothing happens in the network tab after selecting the image, although the upload should be able to be seen from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was using the wrong class name in my HTML.

The following:

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="JQuery">
    <input name="file" type="file" class="cloudinary-fileupload"/>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Should be changed to:

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="JQuery">
    <input name="file" type="file" class="cloudinary_fileupload"/>
    </asp:Panel>
```